# Simple Htaccess redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

For some reason this is not working...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Redirect 301 "/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=179" http://www.mysite.com/a/new/url
```

I have no idea why... If I replace the URL being redirected with another non-existent one (/helloworld) it redirects fine to the new url..

Is it catching on something? I tried escaping (/modules.php\?name=News&file=article&sid=179) but it didn't make any difference, still just 404s.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: 404s? Which page does it redirect to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in the `Redirect` directive, you'll have to use mod_rewrite and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=News&file=article&sid=179
RewriteRule ^/?modules\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/a/new/url? [R=301,L]
# There is a ? here to prevent query strings appending -----^
```

Comment: thank you, OK that finally got me going!! Except here's the URL now: http://www.mysite.com/a/new/url/?name=News&file=article&sid=179. How can I just have the URL be /a/new/url without pasting the old stuff in there?

Comment: @user1556073 Add a **?** to the end of `/a/new/url` so it looks like this: `RewriteRule ^/?modules\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/a/new/url? [R=301,L]`

Comment: that still does the same thing... it adds the query to the end of the new URL. I just want the plain, new URL like it appears in the rewrite rule (I don't want the query on the end). Thanks!

Comment: @user1556073 you've changed the rule to `RewriteRule ^/?modules\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/a/new/url? [R=301,L]`? Note the **`?`** at the end of `url`. And ensure there is no `QSA` flag. Because when I test that rule, nothing is appended to the end.

Comment: this is exactly what I have: *RewriteRule ^/?modules\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/game/32/pc/game1/? [R=301,L]*. My resulting URLS look like this: *http://www.mysite.com/a/new/url/?name=News&file=article&sid=179* Any ideas

Comment: @user1556073 Not sure why it's going to `/a/new/url/` when your rule has it go to `/game/32/pc/game1`

Comment: sorry, I just used different examples, that's all... Let me make it clear. this is exactly what I have: *RewriteRule ^/?modules\.php$ mysite.com/a/new/url/? [R=301,L]*. My resulting URLS look like this: *mysite.com/a/new/url/?name=News&file=article&sid=179* Any ideas?